# Calculating the expected number of zeros under Poisson and Negative Binomial distributions in R

Tags: r, poisson

I know the maths, but how to calculate the expected number of zeros under Poisson and Negative Binomial distributions in R? Is there any function to do so?

Answer (score 3):

You say you know the mathematics, in which case you already know you're calculating *n p(0)*, right?

You already know *n*.

So isn't your question "How do I evaluate *p(0) = P(X=0)* for a Poisson or negative binomial in R?"

Try

`?Poisson`

and

`?NegBinomial`

And you will see there's a `dpois` function for the Poisson, and a similar one for the negative binomial.

So `n*dpois(0,lambda)` (with whatever value you need in place of `lambda`) would give the expected number of zeros from a given Poisson distribution. The negative binomial calculation works similarly.