# How do you calculate the expected number of zeros in a Poisson distributed mixed-effects model in R?

Tags: r, poisson

I am working on a dataset and fit a poisson distributed mixed effects model. I would like to calculate the expected number of zeros that my model predicts and compare that to the observed number of zeros in the actual dataset. Although I have seen many posts discussing the underlying mathematics of this, the code to implement such mathematics is unclear to me and I cannot seem to find any clear answers.

As far as I am aware, I am looking for a way to compute P(Yi=0|xi)=e−λ for a mixed-effects model in R.

A little background on my dataset. The response variable is a count (number of individual butterflies) and my predictor variables are mostly proportions (e.g. proportion of habitat covered by flowers). I also have a random variable: PatchID. I fitted a poisson distributed mixed-effects model in the package lme4.

Model Output:

```
Generalized linear mixed model fit by maximum likelihood (Laplace Approximation) ['glmerMod']
Family: poisson  ( log )
Formula: spp_icarus ~ BareGround + Shrub + Grass + AllFlowers + CowsVetch +  
CanopyCover + avg.bft + season.bft + (1 | PatchID)
Data: icarusdata2

 AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
804.8    835.2   -392.4    784.8      144 

Scaled residuals: 
Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
-4.819 -0.844 -0.350  0.443 77.147 

Random effects:
Groups  Name        Variance Std.Dev.
PatchID (Intercept) 2.69     1.64    
Number of obs: 154, groups:  PatchID, 39

Fixed effects:
        Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   0.3069     0.5750   0.534 0.593512    
BareGround   -5.7246     0.8096  -7.071 1.54e-12 ***
Shrub       -50.1908     5.8837  -8.530  < 2e-16 ***
Grass        -1.3167     0.5608  -2.348 0.018875 *  
AllFlowers   11.2299     1.5986   7.025 2.14e-12 ***
CowsVetch   -51.2781     8.0523  -6.368 1.91e-10 ***
CanopyCover   0.1029     2.3806   0.043 0.965537    
avg.bft     -48.1492     7.0559  -6.824 8.86e-12 ***
season.bft1   2.0350     0.6045   3.367 0.000761 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: Can you share the links you mentioned? BTW, I just saw this https://twitter.com/NPilakouta/status/995982320585920512?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw.

Comment: Hi @RalfStubner! A relevant link for this questions could include: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288824/calculating-the-expected-number-of-zeros-under-poisson-and-negative-binomial-dis and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86841/how-to-calculate-the-expected-zeros-in-a-poisson-distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, my interpretation of [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/86841/how-to-calculate-the-expected-zeros-in-a-poisson-distribution) can be translated into R code as follows. With your fitted model `model` you can predict the expected response for each observation:

```
lambda_hat <- predict(model, type = "response")
```

For a Poisson distribution the expected value corresponds to the lambda parameter. And we know that the probability of zeros is `exp(-lambda)`. So we can calculate the probability of zero for each observation and sum them up to get the expected number of zeros:

```
expected_zeros <- sum(exp(-lambda_hat))
```

Comment: This makes sense and the code worked, but I have one more clarification to ask for. When the probabilities of getting zero are summed across all observations of X, does this yield the expected number of zeros or the expected probability of getting a zero? For example, if, by implementing this code, I get a value of 64.3 for expected_zeros, does this indicate the model predicts 64 zeros out of 154 observations (i.e. 42%) or a predicted 64% zeros?

Comment: @StephanieRivest it is the number of expected zeros. After all this sum can become as large as your number of observations.

Comment: It has been awhile since I've looked at this post, but I am now having some doubts about what the outputted value actually means. Is it (1) the expected number of zeros or (2) the expected probability of getting a zero. According to the Ralf's reply, he would suggest the expected_zeros represents #1 above. However, when looking at other posts (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22288824/calculating-the-expected-number-of-zeros-under-poisson-and-negative-binomial-dis) it seems to me like this value actually represents #2 above. Can anyone provide clarification on this issue?

Comment: @StephanieRivest I can only repeat my argument: It cannot be a probability since it is not guaranteed to be <= 1.

Comment: Thank you for replying @Ralf and my apologies for not getting it right away! I agree with you that the expected_zeros could be > 1 (as I've had this happen before). What I cannot resolve is that I've also tried the ppois function in R and it gives me the same result, expected_zero=0.15. However, on this web page describing how to use the function ppois (http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/probability-distributions/poisson-distribution), they refer to their answer as a probability! My confusion remains!

Comment: @StephanieRivest It is difficult to help you without a concrete example. Can you provide a [mcve] using a dataset that comes with R (or some package) or some random data?